# Xamarin retry failed data request

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, task-parallel-library

[Retry action Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H01kj.png)

I am building a Xamarin iOS & android App, and I want to implement a retry function to all the failed webcall or in case of disconnection, I already use Polly in the BLL side, and I want to give the user the possibility to retry manually as shown on the **above image**.

```
protected List<Task> _taskList;

_taskList.Add(Task.Run(async () =>
{
    try
    {
        **// Webservice Call**
        Task<UtilisateurDTO> utilisateurTask = UserFactory.Login(username, pwd,
            App.Hardware.GetDeviceId());

        UtilisateurDTO utilisateur = await utilisateurTask;

        if (utilisateur != null)
        {
            InvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                **// Set result to ui component**
            });
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        InvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            // Add action button "Retry" to snackBar
            _snackBar = new TTGSnackbar("ex.Message", TTGSnackbarDuration.Forever, "Retry", (obj) => {
                // **Retry all tasks**
                Parallel.ForEach(_taskList, task => task.Start());
            });
            _snackBar.Show();
        });
    }
}));
```

I know that it's not possible to retry completed tasks, and I can't call my web service outside a task (to not block the UI thread), so what's the alternative?

**Update with a solution**

If you want to handle exceptions and retry in one place, here is my solution (not the best cause it reload everything)

// **BaseViewClass**

```
public abstract class BaseViewController:UIViewController
{

    // Function to override in child controllers
    protected abstract void ReloadData(TTGSnackbar obj);

    public void HandleExceptions(Exception e)
    {
        // On commence par cacher la ProgressBar
        InvokeOnMainThread(HideLoadigProgressBar);

        if (e is ConnectionLostException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ConnectionLostException: " + e.ToString());
            InvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                _snackBar = new TTGSnackbar("Connection lost !", TTGSnackbarDuration.Forever, "retry", ReloadData);
                _snackBar.Show();
            });

        }
        else if (e is TimeoutException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("TimeoutException: "+ e.ToString());
            InvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                _snackBar = new TTGSnackbar("TimeoutException", TTGSnackbarDuration.Forever, "Retry", ReloadData);
                _snackBar.Show();
            });
        }
        .....................
}
```

// **Other ViewController**

```
public partial class HomeController : BaseViewController
{
    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        LoadData();

    }

    public void LoadData(){
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            try
            {
                // Web calls
                Task<UtilisateurDTO> getUserTask = AccueilFactory.GetUser();

                UtilisateurDTO utilisateur = await getUserTask;

                // Set UI result
             }
             catch(Exception ex) {
                 HandleExceptions(ex);
             }
        }
   }

    protected override void ReloadData(TTGSnackbar obj)
    {
        LoadData();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to run again all tasks in an exception, why to not just run again fault task?

Comment: That's not the problem, Even if I want to run only one fault task, task.Start() will give an exception as you can't run again a completed task

Comment: Yes. But if you know which tasks fail you can recreate it. In your case with `UserFactory.Login(username, pwd,
            App.Hardware.GetDeviceId())`

Comment: But I think here you want to recall your function. Not only run the task. Think that you have the code that set result in UI, you don't want to write it again

Answer (score 0):

You have to call your function again on exception, not only rerun last task.

Your code will be like this:

`private void Login()
{
    try 
    {
       LoginInner(); // here you call service and update UI
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        InvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            // Add action button "Retry" to snackBar
            _snackBar = new TTGSnackbar("ex.Message", TTGSnackbarDuration.Forever, "Retry", (obj) => {
                // **Retry all tasks**
                Parallel.ForEach(_taskList, LoginInner); // ** call again loginInner **
            });
            _snackBar.Show();
        });
    }
}`

Comment: Thank you, I will try and update the topic with the appropriate code